# iPhone: Properly scaling lines / circle drawn in drawRect

Tags: iphone, uiview, zooming, drawrect

I am drawing custom annotations over an image (circle, arrow etc) in my iPhone app. I allow pinch zooming & drag gestures for these annotations. These annotations are custom made AnnotationView with `drawRect` drawing circle / line etc.

I am finding issues with zooming

Try 1: The zoom is applied by scale transformation to the AnnotationView. Result: the annotations become blurred.

Try 2: To avoid blurring, I added redrawing with co-ords multiplied by scale factor instead of directly manipulating the transformation. This works without blurring, but, soon the circle etc goes out of the views bounds & is clipped.

I could use a bigger frame (size of full image), but, I am keeping the smaller frame so that I can easily move it back to position when it is dragged out of the window by user's zoom / pan gestures.

Question:
Is there a better way to manage this? I would like to zoom without blurring, while also having the ability to move it back to position if it is dragged out of original image bounds.